ReactCommon/TurboModuleBinding.h file not found
System details follows:
System

OS: macOS 14.5
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
Memory: 3.36 GB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash

Binaries

Node: 20.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node

Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn

npm: 10.8.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm Watchman: 2022.09.26.00 -
/usr/local/bin/watchman

Managers:

CocoaPods: 1.15.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod



My pod file
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
platform :ios, '13.0'
prepare_react_native_project!

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled
linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'userApp' do
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', :git => 'https://github.com/Simon-TechForm/google-maps-ios-utils.git', :branch => 'feat/support-apple-silicon'

  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary/Permission-PhotoLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Microphone', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Microphone/Permission-Microphone.podspec"

  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'
  

  # Initialize config from use_native_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  flags = get_default_flags()
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
   # :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'userAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      # Avoid duplicate `folly.framework` build error
      if target.name == 'RCT-Folly'
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name == "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks"
            target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0) # Move to top to avoid duplicates
          end
        end
      end
      
      # Avoid duplicate `fmt.framework` build error
      if target.name == 'fmt'
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name == "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks"
            target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0) # Move to top to avoid duplicates
          end
        end
      end

      # Fix BoringSSL-GRPC flag issue
      if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
        target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
          if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
            flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
            flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
            file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
          end
        end
      end

      if target.name == 'ReactCommon'
           target.build_configurations.each do |config|
             config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
             config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] << "${PODS_ROOT}/../../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
      # Add header search path for "React-NativeModulesApple"
#      if ["React-NativeModulesApple"].include?(target.name)
#        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
#          config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
#          config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] << "${PODS_ROOT}/../../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


I have cleaned derived data and reinstalled all pods, i have removed node modules and reinstalled. Still  issue showing.

can you provide your full error log?
